# PHP Annotation Array (Key, Value)

Tags: php, arrays, annotations

I work with Netbeans 8.0.2.

Is there a way to declare (and with autocomplete usage of course) array key and value types of an @return array annotation?

Like:

```
@return array[string]Class2
```

Or like:

```
@return Class2[string]
```

So Netbeans should have no problems with autocomplete on following foreach:

```
foreach($aArray as $sString => $oClass2){ ... }
```

I know about the following way of annotation:

```
@return Class2[]
```

But in this way I have no clue how to get the autocomplete on the string key.

Sure, "String" - there is no autocomplete, but let's say we want to add another Object instead a string as Key, then how could I inform my IDE to let it know and to get the right autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using netbeans and this way work good:

```
/* @var $data['a'] \SomeClass */
/* @var $data['b'] string */
$data = array(
  "a" => new \SomeClass(),
  "b" => "Dump string"
);
```

It is important to use single * when make this type of comments in netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the key can't be typehinted, but you can typehint the value in foreach loops like this:

```
/**
 * $var $value MyTypeHint
 */
foreach($array as $key => $value){}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be a way. But i can't imagine that there is no possible annotation of an array or an multidimensional array - that would be pretty sad :-/

Comment: The only time I'm aware of where you might have an object as the key would be in SplObjectStorage (in arrays you can only have a string or integer as a key). It's probably just too rare a use case for them to justify the effort.